# How to suppress a third-party warning using warnings.filterwarnings

Tags: python, suppress-warnings, paramiko, pycrypto

I am using Paramiko in my python code (for sftp). Everything works fine except that everytime I import or call a paramiko function. This warning would show up:

```
C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\randpool.py:40: RandomPool_Deprecation
Warning: This application uses RandomPool, which is BROKEN in older releases.  S
ee http://www.pycrypto.org/randpool-broken
  RandomPool_DeprecationWarning)
```

I know that this has to do with the fact that Paramiko is using some Deprecated functionalities of PyCrypto.

My question is, is there a way to suppress this warning programmatically ?
I have tried this:

```
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', \
category=DeprecationWarning, module='paramiko')
```

and even this:

```
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', \
category=DeprecationWarning, module='randpool')
```

before 'import paramiko' statement and before paramiko-specific function calls, but nothing works. This warning keeps showing up no matter what.
If it helps, here's the code in the third party library that prints the warning:

in randpool.py:

```
from Crypto.pct_warnings import RandomPool_DeprecationWarning
import Crypto.Random
import warnings

class RandomPool:
    """Deprecated.  Use Random.new() instead.

    See http://www.pycrypto.org/randpool-broken
    """
    def __init__(self, numbytes = 160, cipher=None, hash=None, file=None):
        warnings.warn("This application uses RandomPool, which is BROKEN in older releases.  See http://www.pycrypto.org/randpool-broken",
            RandomPool_DeprecationWarning)
```

If you know a way around this, please help me shut this warning off.

Answer (score 69):

Easiest way would be as the warnings module suggests [here](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings):

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    import paramiko
```

Comment: How would you modify this to only filter the particular warning OP mentions?

Comment: @VF1 See [the answer by Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245433/5728089)

Answer (score 30):

The `module` argument to `warnings.filterwarnings` takes a case-sensitive regular expression which should match the fully qualified module name, so

```
warnings.filterwarnings(
    action='ignore',
    category=DeprecationWarning,
    module=r'.*randpool'
)
```

or

```
warnings.filterwarnings(
    action='ignore',
    category=DeprecationWarning,
    module=r'Crypto\.Utils\.randpool'
)
```

should work. You may need to write `RandomPool_DeprecationWarning` explicitly instead of `DeprecationWarning` if for some reason `RandomPool_DeprecationWarning` is not a subclass of `DeprecationWarning`.

You can also disable the warning on the command line when you invoke the script by passing the `-W` option to the interpreter like so:

```
$ python -W ignore::RandomPool_DeprecationWarning:Crypto.Utils.randpool: my_script.py
```

The `-W` takes filters in the format `action:message:category:module:lineno`, where this time `module` must exactly match the (fully-qualified) module name where the warning is raised.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html?highlight=warnings#the-warnings-filter and https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w

Comment: first `import` the custom warning and then use it in `category`

Answer (score 24):

To filter only a specific warning:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', SpecificWarningObject)

    #do something that raises a Warning
```

Comment: It has been a while, but I still wonder (and don't have a good answer): how do I get the 'SpecificWarningObject' object?

Comment: Here, SpecificWarningObject is just a placeholder for whatever warning you want to filter. Do something like `from mymodule import SpecificWarningObject` and replace "SpecificWarningObject" with the name of the warning you want to ignore.

Comment: Ah yes, I get the part about subbing in the object - but I have no idea how to find where to import it from? I am looking for these two warning:
numpy\lib\function_base.py:2526: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  c = cov(x, y, rowvar)
\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2455: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide c *= np.true_divide(1, fact)

Comment: RuntimeWarning is a built-in so you don't need to import anything.

Comment: But that will ignore all runtimewarnings, not just the two I am worried about

Comment: Ah then you will need to use `filterwarnings` and the `message` arg.

Answer (score 11):

The most flexible way is to combine [`warnings.filterwarnings()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) (or [`warnings.simplefilter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter)) with the [`warnings.catch_warnings()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings) context manager. This way you ge the flexibility of `filterwarnings` but the filtering is only applied inside the `with` block:

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        action='ignore',
        category=SomeWarningClass,
        message='some message')
   
    # Do stuff that causes the warning
```

See [The Warnings Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) in the docs for the descriptions of the arguments for `filterwarnings`.

### Full example

Here is a full example with a custom warning:

```py
import warnings

# Custom warning class for the example
class MyWarning(UserWarning):
    pass

def function_that_issues_warning(num):
    print(num)
    warnings.warn("This is a warning", MyWarning)


with warnings.catch_warnings():
    function_that_issues_warning(1) # issues warning
    warnings.filterwarnings(
        action="ignore", category=MyWarning, message="This is a warning"
    )

    function_that_issues_warning(2) # Warning is filtered
function_that_issues_warning(3) # issues warning
```

##### Example output

```
1
.\test_warnings.py:10: MyWarning: This is a warning
  warnings.warn("This is a warning", MyWarning)
2
3
.\test_warnings.py:10: MyWarning: This is a warning
  warnings.warn("This is a warning", MyWarning)
```

Comment: Hi @np8 for me it works using `warnings.simplefilter('ignore')` rather than `warnings.filterwarnings()` as per the current [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings).

Comment: What happened when you tried `warnings.filterwarnings()`?