# How to suppress graphviz warnings in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, warnings, graphviz

I'm using the graphviz module to render a network of nodes and links.

I use small circles as node's shape, so the labels are intentionally bigger than the nodes.

As a consequence, I get the following warning:

> "Warning: node 'wave', graph 'N' size too small for label"

'Wave' is just an example of a node's label.

I get lots of this [warnings because of the high quantity of nodes (screencapture).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVBn1.png)

So, my question is: **How can I suppress warnings like those?**

The graphviz command I'm using is:

```
n.view()  # n is my digraph
```

I have already tried the suggestions from:

[How to suppress a third-party warning using warnings.filterwarnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920502/how-to-suppress-a-third-party-warning-using-warnings-filterwarnings)

[How to redirect python warnings to a custom stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858916/how-to-redirect-python-warnings-to-a-custom-stream)

But nothing so far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Eli Bendersky's excellent page: [Redirecting all kinds of stdout in Python](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)

After replacing `stdout` with `stderr`, Eli's solution worked on graphviz for me.

If you happen to be using [Evince](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Evince), Ubuntu's builtin PDF viewer, see:

https://superuser.com/questions/980237/silence-evinces-warnings-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For graphviz, as of v0.11, there is a `silent` option for the `.draw()` method (see [graphviz docs:graphviz.view](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.view)).

Apparently not on windows.

---

This applies to those using networkx (which uses pygraphviz) or pygraphviz.

In pygraphviz, the warnings are collected and then pushed using the [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module (see [pygraphviz/agraph.py:1390](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/blob/225d45fe88241562cf55201e1b7b604b242ff7e0/pygraphviz/agraph.py#L1390)).

You can therefore silent the warnings specifically when drawing:
[warnings docs:Temporarily Suppressing Warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings)

```py
import warnings

<create graph etc>

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    g.draw()
```