# pytest : is it possible to disable the warnings that originate from a specific directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Situation is as follows :

I am redoing all the test suites for my work and there is a LOT of warnings but not all of them I can fix.
More specifically, the project has dependencies that I cannot interfer with and cannot fix them

Here is an exemple :

`/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py:275: DeprecationWarning: 'ERROR_404_HELP' config setting is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use 'RESTX_ERROR_404_HELP' instead.`

In this case the warning originates from the venv directory and I cannot do anything about it for now

How can I just have all the other warnings without having to scroll through hundreds of warnings to find them ?
I would like to ignore all warnings that have `venv/` in their path

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53706908/17200348) answer help?

Comment: unless I am not understanding the way it works ( which is very possible ) I would have to add an ignore rule for all  the different warnings which would be a lot.

Comment: It would be worth a shot using [`pip freeze -l`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-l) and generating the warning suppressions from the output of that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of this as suppressing warnings from a specific directory, but from a *module*. As the warning is generated by the `warnings` module, you can also use `warnings` to suppress it. Add the following to the test module that triggers the warning:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", DeprecationWarning, 'flask_restx\.api', 275)
```

This is very precise: it will disable `DeprecationWarning`s produced by line 275 of any module whose full name starts with `flask_restx.api`. If this pops up on multiple lines, you can remove `275` and let the default of covering *any* line in the matched module(s) be used.

`flask_restx\.api` is a regular expression; you can modify that to match multiple modules from which the warning might be raised. You can also simply define multiple filters to cover multiple modules if the regular expression would get too confusing.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I am getting a ``AttributeError: module 'warnings' has no attribute 'DeprecationWarning'`` although I am using Python 3.9.4 and I can see it in the documentation

Comment: My bad; none of those exceptions are attributes of the `warnings` module; they are in the built-in namespace.